# Transfer Class to other Class on ListActivity

Tags: java, android, mobile

I have an Activity called `ListUserActivity` that receives a list from an activity called `BD.class` where I have the Adapter to my SQLite database.

I am facing problems with this, and I want transfer the class `Buscar()` from `BD.class` to `ListUserActivity` inside.

`ListUserActivity`:

```
package br.exemplosqlite;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;

 public class ListUsersActivity extends ListActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_users);

    BD bd = new BD(this);

    List<Produtos> list = bd.buscar();
    setListAdapter(new ProdutosAdapter(this, list));
}
   }
```

This is my `BD.class`

```
    package br.exemplosqlite;

   import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.List;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.provider.SyncStateContract;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class BD {


private SQLiteDatabase bd;

public BD(Context context){
    BDCore auxBd = new BDCore(context);
    bd = auxBd.getWritableDatabase();
}


public void inserir(Produtos produtos){
    ContentValues valores = new ContentValues();
    valores.put("item", produtos.getItem());
    valores.put("coligada", produtos.getColigada());
    valores.put("filial", produtos.getFilial());


    bd.insert("produtos2", null, valores);
}


public void atualizar(Produtos produtos){
    ContentValues valores = new ContentValues();

    valores.put("item", produtos.getItem());
    valores.put("coligada", produtos.getColigada());
    valores.put("filial", produtos.getFilial());

    bd.update("produtos2", valores, "_id = ?", new String[]{""+produtos.getId()});
}


public void deletar(Produtos produtos){
    bd.delete("produtos2", "_id = "+produtos.getId(), null);
}


public List<Produtos> buscar(){

    List<Produtos> list = new ArrayList<Produtos>();
    String[] colunas = new String[]{"_id", "item", "coligada","filial"};

    Cursor cursor = bd.rawQuery("select * from produtos2",null);

    if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        do{

            Produtos p = new Produtos();
            p.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
            p.setItem(cursor.getString(1));
            p.setColigada(cursor.getString(2));
            p.setFilial(cursor.getString(3));
            list.add(p);

        }while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    return(list);
}
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why you use bd??

use `SQLiteDatabase` `Object` to read your database from `SQliteDatabase`

```
public List<Produtos> buscar() {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    List<Produtos> list = new ArrayList<Produtos>();
    String[] colunas = new String[]{"_id", "item", "coligada", "filial"};

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from produtos2", null);

    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        do {

            Produtos p = new Produtos();
            p.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
            p.setItem(cursor.getString(1));
            p.setColigada(cursor.getString(2));
            p.setFilial(cursor.getString(3));
            list.add(p);

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    return (list);
}
```

Comment: it's look like correct. Just make sure about context is Not null ..Hope this will work for you.